# CentOS 5.5 server dropping & blocking connection

Tags: networking, centos, timeout

I'm running a *CentOS release 5.5 (Final)* server running the LAMP stack amongst other things.
When working on a web project with numerous active connections to the server box (Plesk over HTTP, SSH and FTP), the server randomly drops the connection. When this happens, the box essentially becomes invisible to me from my current location until I reset my local broadband connection. It does not respond to ping via hostname or IP. It does however, remain accessible from all other locations. I have tested this numerous times by successfully accessing the server using TOR despite being unable to connect directly.

For example, trying to reconnect directly over SSH after the connection has been dropped:

```
 ssh root@xxxxxxx.al
 ssh: connect to host xxxxxxx.al port 22: Operation timed out
```

My uneducated guess would be to suspect some type of upper connection limit that I am exceeding by having numerous connections active at one time, after which I am placed on a hammer list until I reconnect from a new location?

Thoughts and suggestions greatly welcomed.

Comment: I have the same problem in CentOS 6